# ::after and ::before works with which input types

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

**The question is:**

**- Where can I use ::after and ::before ?**

**- Is there a documentation that tells me which element accepts it ?**

I'd like to know if there is any documentation or article that tells me where exactly one can use `::after` and `::before`

I've seen that it's does not work with  for instance, I believe that it is like this because the `img` tag does not need and closing `</img>`.

BUT! the `<input>` tag also doesn't need a closing tag, so, my presumption is wrong, I guess.

PS: I know that with JQuery you can do everything, but that is not the answer I'm looking for.

Thanks!

Comment: No... You can't use `::after` and `::before` with `<input />` tags.

Comment: These pseudo elements are supposed to be rendered the same way, as if they were an actual first or last _child element_ of the element you are applying them to. So, answer the question “can `input` have child elements” for yourself, and you got your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the browser implementation.
Although it doesn't tell exactly with which filed you can use it, [this link](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_elements.asp) gives you a glimpse of how and when to use it.